# What triggers asking connected device to reconnect to WiFi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I am assuming that changing the SSID and security would require the connected device to re-connect to the WiFi network. So, if that is true, in theory I can set anything in my WiFi router if it still retain the same SSID and security, is this about right?

**Context**

My house has 6 IP CCTVs, some of which are hard to reach, so I really avoid having to reconnect to the WiFi network. The way my network set up is I have a main router A and router B, which connected to router A through ethernet cable. With the current setting, router A and B has different SSID, so I would need to manually change the network should I am closer to the other, which is not ideal. Therefore, I would like to follow [this](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/setting-up-wireless-routers-same-ssid-68675.html) guide.

My CCTVs are connected to router B, so instead of copying the setting from main router, like in the guide, I would do the other way around — matching the main router's SSID and security to router B. Aside from that, the others should be the same.

Again, my question is this — in the above method, although changing how the router behave, I did not change the SSID and security of router B, so is it correct to assume that it won't require the devices to reconnect to it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as you seem to be interested in this topic, I will give you a general explanation of what you are trying to set up, as this will make it easier for me to write my answer and you are learning something in the process.

What you are calling Router A in your question is in fact the only real router in your setup. The Router B will become (or is in fact already) a so called Access Point or short AP. It's sole purpose is to translate/convert the incoming network traffic or signal over the ethernet cable to a wireless signal that will be transmitted via Wifi. In comparison to an AP, a router is a management unit in your network. It assigns more or less unique addresses to all devices that are connected to your network, no matter if wired or wireless. Only by doing this, you can reach out to a single device without sending the same data to all devices and hoping that the wanted device is the only one that answers.

Now to the part where you need to configure some settings:

The only things other devices in your network will see are the SSID and BSSID (if connected wireless) or of course the hardware address of your used LAN port if connected via ethernet cable. Everything else inside your router that you as an end user can configure via a web interface is kind of a black box to all other devices. Meaning that most of your devices won't care what you do with your network infrastructure as long as they get an IP-address in order to communicate with one another and the Internet.

One last thing, in my network I have multiple devices that I cannot access that easily as well, and when I need to make changes to the network, I can connect to them via another web interface and just load another profile I can create there, in order to make them connect to the new SSID after a reboot. Then I can do whatever I want with the routers or APs and as long as after the procedure the new SSID matches the one I set up in the profile, they will connect to the new network. Maybe that works for you too, just take a look into the manual.

**tldr:**

As long as you do not change the SSID to something new (something your CCTVs don't know i.e. the old one of your Router A) there should not be a problem.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. If any questions persist, just ask. I will probably monitoring this question for the next few days, so feel free to reach out.